# how to stop my counter variable from getting overridden from each row?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, interface

I have a stepper counter for each row in my recycler view, and as stepper gets touched I want my shopping cart at bottom badge to change, and I achieved this through interface callbacks, but the problem is every time I go to a new row counter, it counter reset my shopping cart badge, I just want all row counter to add up to the badge and not being replaced for each row, how can I achieve this?

[image]

RecyclerViewAdapter (which has the counter)

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Food> data;
FoodListFragment.ListenerFoodListFragment listenerFoodListFragment;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Food> data,
                           FoodListFragment.ListenerFoodListFragment listenerFoodListFragment) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.listenerFoodListFragment = listenerFoodListFragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_food
            , parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvFoodTitle;
    ImageView tvFoodImage;
    TextView tvPrice;
    StepperTouch stepperTouch;
    public RadioGroup radioButton;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segmented2);

        radioButton.setOnClickListener(v ->
                Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());


        final FoldingCell fc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);


        fc.setOnClickListener(v -> fc.toggle(false));

        // the counter 
        stepperTouch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stepperTouch);
        stepperTouch.setMinValue(1);
        stepperTouch.setMaxValue(10);
        stepperTouch.setSideTapEnabled(true);
        stepperTouch.setCount(1);
        stepperTouch.addStepCallback((value, positive) -> {
            listenerFoodListFragment.sendToCart(value);
            if (value == 10) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You have reached maximum order quantity"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, value + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
}
```

FoodListFragment (which has the cart badge)

```
public class FoodListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
private BadgeHolderLayout badgeHolderLayout;
private List<Food> foods;

// interface to receive counter value and display it on cart badge
public interface ListenerFoodListFragment {
    void sendToCart(int value);
}

ListenerFoodListFragment listenerFoodListFragment;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listenerFoodListFragment = (ListenerFoodListFragment) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d("FoodListFragment", "onAttach: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public FoodListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    badgeHolderLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    foods = new ArrayList<>();


    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));
    foods.add(new Food("chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));

    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), foods, listenerFoodListFragment);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}

public void updateCartValue(int value) {
    badgeHolderLayout.setCountWithAnimation(value);
}
}
```

MainActivity (which I used to update fragment cart value with recycler view adapter stepper count value)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WelcomeFragment.ArrowBtnListener
    , SetupAccountFragment.BtnOkListener, FoodListFragment.ListenerFoodListFragment {

FragmentManager fm;
FlowingDrawer flowingDrawer;
FoodListFragment foodListFragment;

// sending the counter value to be shown on cart badge
@Override
public void sendToCart(int value) {
    foodListFragment.updateCartValue(value);
}

// for account setup fragment
@Override
public void btnOkMethod() {
     foodListFragment = new FoodListFragment();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, foodListFragment)
            .commit();

}
// for account setup fragment


@Override
public void onArrowClick() {

    SetupAccountFragment setupAccountFragment = new SetupAccountFragment();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, setupAccountFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
// for welcome fragment


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    flowingDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    flowingDrawer.setTouchMode(ElasticDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL);



    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        // adding fragment to main container
        fragment = new WelcomeFragment();

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
                .replace(R.id.id_container_menu, new FoodCategoryFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

}

// make back button close navigation drawer
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (flowingDrawer.isLaidOut()) {
        flowingDrawer.closeMenu();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `adapterPosition` of `ViewHolder` to the method `sendToCart`:

```
listenerFoodListFragment.sendToCart(value, getAdapterPosition());
```

In `Activity`, you maintain the cart value mapped to the `adapterPosition`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> cartValues = new HashMap();

public void sendToCart(int value, int adapterPosition) {

    cartValues.put(adapterPosition, value);
    foodListFragment.updateCartValue(getTotalValue());
}

private int getTotalValue() {
    int value = 0
    for (Integer key : cartValues.keySet()) {
        value += cartValues.get(key)
    }
    return value;
}
```

You can also have a unique id for each Food, and map the cart value with the Food id instead of `adapterPosition`.

Comment: Thank you for your help it works, but just the `String` in loop needs to be replaced with `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Edit your `updateCartValue` method to this :

```
public void updateCartValue(int value, boolean add) {
   int prevCount = badgeHolderLayout.getCount();
   if(add)
      badgeHolderLayout.setCountWithAnimation(prevCount + value);
   else
      badgeHolderLayout.setCountWithAnimation(prevCount - value);
}
```

You need to also send if the value is being added or subtracted from previous cart value.